# How to make the last row of a table frozen?

Tags: html, css

I'm able to make the first row of an HTML table frozen similar to Freeze Panes in MS Word, but not sure how to do it for the last row in the table.

I have this code:

```css
.myTable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 650px;
  display: block;
}

.table-header-col {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #f5f6f8;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr style="height: 55px; margin: 0px;">
      <th class="table-header-col"></th>
      <th class="table-header-col">Description </th>
      <th class="table-header-col">Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td>2.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td>3.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I only included two rows here for an example, but if I have 50 rows, the user will have to scroll to get to the last row which contains a total. Is it possible to make that row Freeze similar to the way I'm making the header row freeze above?

Comment: You can't see the top row freezing with my example because there aren't enough rows to make it scroll. I didn't really want to make the question extra long with 50 rows of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you want something like this :)

```css
.myTable {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 650px;
   display: block;
}
table tbody tr:last-child{
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   background-color: #f5f6f8;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr style="height: 55px; margin: 0px;">
      <th class="table-header-col"></th>
      <th class="table-header-col">Description </th>
      <th class="table-header-col">Amount</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>Bananas</td>
       <td>2.00</td>      
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td>3.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you mean to write "bottom: 0" instead of "top: 0"?

Comment: no add position sticky

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one.
worked for me:

```css
table{
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 42px;
   border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 25px 0;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    min-width: 400px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

table ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}


table > thead {
  height: 30px;
  text-align: end;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
table > thead > tr{
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #009879;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
}
table > thead > tr > th{
   text-align: end;
}

table > tbody{
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: pink;
}

table > tbody > tr{
  height: 30px;
  text-align: end;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}


table > thead > tr > th,
table > tbody > tr > td{

 padding: 12px 15px;

}


table > tbody > tr{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

table > tbody > tr:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #009879;
}

table > tbody > tr:last-child{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>text1.1</td>
       <td>text1.2</td>
       <td>text1.3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>text2.1</td>
       <td>text2.2</td>
       <td>text2.3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>text3.1</td>
       <td>text3.2</td>
       <td>text3.3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>text4.1</td>
       <td>text4.2</td>
       <td>text4.3</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>text5.1</td>
       <td>text5.2</td>
       <td>text5.3</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>text6.1</td>
       <td>text6.2</td>
       <td>text6.3</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>text7.1</td>
       <td>text7.2</td>
       <td>text7.3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>text8.1</td>
       <td>text8.2</td>
       <td>text8.3</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>text9 .1</td>
       <td>text9 .2</td>
       <td>text9 .3</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```